# Getting all related rows that a value is included in, in a mapping table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I don't even know how to start my search on this one.

Let me explain what I'm trying to do :

I have a variable - value mapping table.
**Several values can be assigned to a variable, and the same value can be assigned to many variables**.

The user is able to delete variables/values.
However, **a value should not be allowed to be deleted if there are any variables that only have this specific value assigned to them**. Otherwise the variables would remain undeleted, but with 0 values assigned, which is wrong.

Now, at the point where the user tries to delete a value from a specific variable, I want to check :

**IF for the selected valueID there are any variableIDs that only have one valueID assigned to them, and that valueID is the one the user is trying to delete.**
If so, then abort. Otherwise proceed.

Is this possible in any way?

Table Names :

```
Variable
Value
Variable_Value ( mapping table )
```

Field Names ( in all tables ) :

```
Variable_ID
Value_ID
```

Example below :

```
For example Variable_ID 5 only has Value_ID 10 assigned to it. 
If a user selects a Variable_ID, he sees all assigned Value_IDs 
and is able to select one and try to delete it. So, a user could click 
on Variable_ID 3 and try to delete Value_ID 10. That shouldn't 
be possible if that specific Value_ID is the only assigned 
value to any other Variable, because that would leave that 
variable with no Value_IDs.
```

[image]

Comment: Not sure I'm getting you. Some example data before and after would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By breaking down your requirements i think the logic of what you need, is something like this:

1. First get the `VariableId`s for a specific `ValueId` :

   ```
   DECLARE @VALUE_ID INT
   SET @VALUE_ID = 10;

   SELECT DISTINCT VariableId
   FROM VARIABLE_VALUE
   WHERE ValueId = @VALUE_ID
   ```
2. After this query, you will have all the `VariableId`s that have that specific value. Then, *for each* of these `VariableId`s, you need to `COUNT` the number of values they have.

   ```
   SELECT VariableId, COUNT(ValueId) as Values
   FROM VARIABLE_VALUE
   WHERE VariableId IN (--- The result of the query in step 1 ---)
   GROUP BY VariableId
   ```
3. If there is **even one** `VariableId` of which the count returned 1, then you **cannot** proceed with the delete.

Ps. I don't know if the SQL is valid, I just wanted to present the general idea behind my answer.

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm. Just cut & paste the first query in the parentheses of the second one.

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```
DECLARE @Value INT -- the right datatype here
DECLARE @VariableId INT -- the right datatype here
SET @Value = 10
SET @VariableId = 1

;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  *, COUNT(*) OVER() Total,
            COUNT(CASE WHEN Value = @Value THEN 1 END) OVER() TotalValue
    FROM Variable_Value
    WHERE VariableId = @VariableId
)
DELETE FROM CTE
WHERE Total = TotalValue
```

Comment: what does COUNT(CASE WHEN Value = @Value THEN 1 END) TotalValue this do?? will this always be 0 or 1?

Comment: @АртёмЦарионов Not necessarily, but it might be that way for the data op has. It counts how many times a variable has the value `@value`.

Answer (score 0):

OK, maybe I'm getting the question better.

Let's just focus on the statement *if there are any variables that only have this specific value assigned to them*.

So, you want a query of all the variables, (1) with this value, and (2) that is it's only value.

```
SELECT AA.Variable_ID
FROM Variable_Value AA
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Variable_Value BB
    ON AA.Value_ID = ? AND AA.Variable_ID = BB.Variable_ID AND BB.Value_ID <> ?
GROUP BY AA.Variable_ID
```

These are the variables which *can* be deleted.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable time Marlin. Another member has already posted an answer that works for me. Check it out.